# Are there downsides to setting path locations to symlinks?

Tags: environment-variables, path, java

I'm setting JAVA_HOME and using the alternatives location of

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```

Which is a simlink to the absolute path of the current active installation.

Are there downsides to using this symlinked location?

Other posts I've read suggest oneliners which end up pointing to the absolute path; for example:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

I just don't know why no one has suggested to use the simple location I've set. So far I haven't encountered any issues but perhaps there are some niche cases where this solution wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the symlink is fine in this case and is often preferable.  For example, say you have something like:

```
/opt/some-program-2.0/bin/
```

that contains a set of binaries, you might then create a symbolic link:

```
/opt/some-program -> /opt/some-program-2.0
```

and add `/opt/some-program/bin` to the PATH.  In the future, when `some-program-3.0` comes out, you can create:

```
/opt/some-program-3.0/
```

and update the symlink to point to the new directory.  This way, nothing else has to change.

Distro's management of JVMs often follow this pattern.

Comment: I agree. Switching between Oracle Java and OpenJDK would be easier, too.

Comment: Thank you Andy & Michael. My thoughts were the same and I was very confused as to why no one had ever suggested this in all the threads I found. I thought that perhaps some processes could not follow a symlink but I guess not!

Comment: @Andy Dalton You are absolutely right about symlinks, however I encountered issues when the overlaying application uses this symlink sometimes goes for the exact absolute path. For eg: Installing java in `/usr/lib/java1-8-345/`  and then setting up a symlink to  `/usr/lib/jvm`  and set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm`  in tomcat , when the tomcat starts up it uses the symlink but expands to the actual JVM folder as `/usr/lib/java1-8-345/`. This will become an issue when new jdk version installs via yum update. I think this is purely on tomcat side. Is there any way we can fix that up ?